# Dynamic UITableViewCell content does not expand cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I have a storyboard with several different types of prototype cells with UILabels containing dynamic data. In my storyboard, the cell looks like this:

[image]

The UILabel's Lines property is set to zero to allow multiple lines of text. It is pinned to the top, left, right of the content view and to the nearest neighbor on the bottom (the blue line). The blue line is pinned to the left and right of the content view and to the UILabel at the top, and the UITextView at the bottom.The UITextView is pinned to the content view on the bottom, left and right, and to the blue line at the top.

When I run the app I get the following:

[image]

So the UILabel is forcing everything else down, as it should be, but the cell's height does not change as I want it to and thus the text view is being clipped off by the cell's fixed height. It was my assumption that if everything were pinned at the top and bottom, then the content view would be forced to expand. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the suggestions others have made, are you setting preferredMaxLayoutWidth on your multi-line label?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have set your constraints correctly, just make sure that delegates are as below:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 44;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

(If your constraints are set correctly from top to bottom)And that's it, you dont have to do anything else, auto layout will do its work smartly.

Comment: Just as a side note - that won't work on iOS 7, you'd have to implement the `heightForRow...` to adjust dynamically yourself.

Comment: Whenever I use UITableViewAutomaticDimension in any way, the cell height defaults to what appears to be 44 and the UILabel only returns one line of truncated text

Comment: Have you changed Labels Line Break Mode to Word Wrap?

Comment: Yes, using word wrap had no effect

Comment: Is your TextView's height set to fix height? Set height constraint to your TextView.

Comment: Bharat - that was the culprit. My text view did not have a height constraint. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Auto-Layout constraint 
 
try 
**cell.contentView.LayoutIfNeeded** statement **in cellForRowIndexPath** just before returning cell and **HeightForRowAtIndexPath** method

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure all your vertical constraints are set and correct top to bottom, try setting `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` explicitly.