# swift , how to make table view cell have dynamic height

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

i have cell have UITextView , but this TextView have dynamic height 
and can i edit this text view in run time 
how to change the height of this cell when TextView is Changed

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777477/dynamic-uitableviewcell-content-does-not-expand-cell/35777859#35777859.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use auto resizable cells to achieve this task. For use reusable cells , you should set UITextViewConstrain all your vertical constraints are set and correct top to bottom and put this one in viewDidLoad()

```
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: but in run time the height of the cell in dont change when i add text in textview or delete text 
i want to change the height of this cell in run time

Comment: After you've changed the contenet give tableView.reloadData()